# Unable to load Universal Windows Platform (UWP - Windows 10) Project in VS2017

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

UWP Project was working fine previously, I dont know exactly for what reason it stopped working. Project Migrated and Could not able to load the project later on.

Project is working properly in other Laptop which has same configuration VS 2017

Re Installed VS 2017 - Issue not resolved.

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{2A28EF1A-F0C8-44F8-A80C-B2D1B6B6C809}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>AppContainerExe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>YazmiApp</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>YazmiApp</AssemblyName>
    <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17134.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{A5A43C5B-DE2A-4C0C-9213-0A381AF9435A};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <PackageCertificateKeyFile>YazmiApp_StoreKey.pfx</PackageCertificateKeyFile>
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>False</AppxAutoIncrementPackageRevision>
    <AppxPackageDir>E:\Projects\AppPackages\</AppxPackageDir>
    <AppxBundle>Always</AppxBundle>
    <AppxBundlePlatforms>x86</AppxBundlePlatforms>
    <PackageCertificateThumbprint>982F755C362284C081B59F0A6B1464B2AC243E6D</PackageCertificateThumbprint>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-arm;win10-arm-aot;win10-x86;win10-x86-aot;win10-x64;win10-x64-aot</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>false</EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|ARM'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|ARM'">
    <OutputPath>bin\ARM\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>ARM</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>false</EnableGatekeeperAnalysis>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NETFX_CORE;WINDOWS_UWP;CODE_ANALYSIS;CODE_ANALYSIS</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <NoWarn>;2008</NoWarn>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <UseVSHostingProcess>false</UseVSHostingProcess>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <Prefer32Bit>true</Prefer32Bit>
    <UseDotNetNativeToolchain>true</UseDotNetNativeToolchain>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\AssessmentAttemptedDetailsManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\AssessmentManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\ChapterManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\CommonManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\ContentManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\CourseManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\ExtAppsManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\GradeManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\LabelManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\NoteManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\PageManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\PartnerManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\QuestionManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\QuestionsAttemptedDetailsManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\SubjectManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\TopicManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\UserActivityManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\UserCommonInfoManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="BusinessModel\UserManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Common\Controls\ChangePasswordDialog.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ChangePasswordDialog.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Common\Controls\SettingsDialog.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SettingsDialog.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Data\SQLiteDataManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Landing.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Landing.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MainView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>MainView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\Assessment.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\AssessmentAttemptedDetails.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\AssessmentDetails.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Chapter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Content.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ContentDetails.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Course.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\ExtApps.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Grade.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Label.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Note.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Page.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Partner.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Question.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\QuestionsAttemptedDetails.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Settings.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Stage.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Subject.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Tag.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\Topic.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UniversalSearchModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\User.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UserActivity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\UserCommonInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Pages\AssessmentStartView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AssessmentStartView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\AssessmentView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>AssessmentView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\ChaptersView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ChaptersView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\ContentsView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ContentsView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\ProfileView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ProfileView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\ToolsView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ToolsView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\LoginView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>LoginView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\NotesView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>NotesView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\QuestionsView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>QuestionsView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\ResultView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ResultView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\SubjectsView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>SubjectsView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Pages\TopicsView.xaml.cs">
      <DependentUpon>TopicsView.xaml</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\BoolToBrushConverter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\CommonConstants.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\CommonUtility.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\DownloadManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\BooleanToIconConverter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\HttpDownloadManager.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Utility\ServiceWrapper.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\AssessmentStartViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\AssessmentViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\ChaptersViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\ContentsViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\LoginViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\MasterSync.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\NoteViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\PageViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\ProfileViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\QuestionViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\ResultViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\SubjectsViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\ToolsViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModel\TopicsViewModel.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </AppxManifest>
    <None Include="YazmiApp_StoreKey.pfx" />
    <None Include="YazmiApp_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\assessment.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\defaultfile.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\ed_1.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\logo1240.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NewStoreLogo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NewStoreLogo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NewStoreLogo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NewStoreLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NewStoreLogo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\NoteIcon.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square310x310Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square310x310Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square310x310Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square310x310Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-16.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-24.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-256.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-32.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.altform-unplated_targetsize-48.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-32.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square71x71Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square71x71Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square71x71Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square71x71Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\topic-default.ico" />
    <Content Include="Assets\topic-default.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-125.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-150.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\default-profile.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\User.png" />
    <None Include="Package.StoreAssociation.xml" />
    <Content Include="Properties\Default.rd.xml" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\login_bg.jpeg" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\subject.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\textureBlack1200.png" />
    <Content Include="Resources\Images\topic.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
    <Page Include="Common\Controls\ChangePasswordDialog.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Common\Controls\SettingsDialog.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Landing.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="MainView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\AssessmentStartView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\AssessmentView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\ChaptersView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\ContentsView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\ProfileView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\ToolsView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\LoginView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\NotesView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\QuestionsView.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\ResultView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\SubjectsView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Pages\TopicsView.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
    </Page>
    <Page Include="Resources\Styles\CommonDictionary.xaml">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Page>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SQLite">
      <Version>1.1.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform">
      <Version>5.3.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLiteNetExtensions">
      <Version>1.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCL">
      <Version>3.8.7.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <SDKReference Include="Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=14.0">
      <Name>Visual C++ 2015 Runtime for Universal Windows Platform Apps</Name>
    </SDKReference>
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsDesktop, Version=10.0.17134.0">
      <Name>Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP</Name>
    </SDKReference>
    <SDKReference Include="WindowsMobile, Version=10.0.17134.0">
      <Name>Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP</Name>
    </SDKReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '' or '$(VisualStudioVersion)' &lt; '14.0' ">
    <VisualStudioVersion>14.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" />
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>
```

Comment: Try create a new black project and see what happens. Could it possible that template is not installed or missing on your current PC? I mean the UWP project template.

Comment: Thank u for ur response. I clicked on "repair" from VS installer, after repair it started working..!

Comment: Well. Then it might be a Visual Studio issue. Glad to know it works.